# Python 2.7 : How to reduce time to get data percentage of a file?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writting a python code to get percentage of each bytes contained in a file. Then check if percentage is less than a given limit and display the byte value (as hex) + percentage if over.

My code works great but it is very time consuming. It take approx 1 minute for a 190KB file.

```
import time

def string2bytes(data):
    return "".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in data)

startTime = time.time()

# get datas from file
f = open("myfile.bin","rb")
filedata = f.read()
size = f.tell()
f.close

# count each data, check percentage and store to a dictionnary if upper than 0.50%
ChkResult = True
r = {}
for data in filedata:
    c = float(filedata.count(data)) / size * 100 
    if c > 0.50:
        ChkResult = False
        tag = string2bytes(data).upper()
        r[tag] = c

# print result
if ChkResult:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "DANGER!"
    print "Any bytes be less than 0.50%%."
    for x in sorted(r.keys()):
        print "    0x%s is %.2f%%"%((x), r[x])

print "Done in %.2f seconds."%(time.time() - startTime)
```

Do you have any idea to reduce this time with same result? Staying with python 2.7.x (for many reasons).
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Counter`<sup>[[docs]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)</sup> to prevent `O(n^2)` time:

You are calling `count` n times. `count` is `O(n)`.

```
import time
from collections import Counter

def string2bytes(data):
    return "".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in data)

startTime = time.time()

# get datas from file
f = open("myfile.bin","rb")
filedata = f.read()
size = f.tell()
f.close

# count each data, check percentage and store to a dictionnary if upper than 0.50%
ChkResult = True
r = {}
for k,v in Counter(filedata).items():
    c = float(v) / size * 100 
    if c > 0.50:
        ChkResult = False
        tag = string2bytes(k).upper()
        r[tag] = c

# print result
if ChkResult:
    print "OK"
else:
    for x in sorted(r.keys()):
        print "    0x%s is %.2f%%"%((x), r[x])

print "Done in %.2f seconds."%(time.time() - startTime)
```

---

or slightly more succinctly:

```
import time
from collections import Counter

def fmt(data):
    return "".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in data).upper()

def pct(v, size):
    return float(v) / size * 100

startTime = time.time()

with open("myfile.bin","rb") as f:
    counts = Counter(f.read())
    size = f.tell()

threshold = size * 0.005
err = {fmt(k):pct(v, size) for k,v in counts.items() if v > threshold }

if not err:
    print "OK"
else:
    for k,v in sorted(err.items()):
        print "    0x{} is {:.2f}%".format(k, v)

print "Done in %.2f seconds."%(time.time() - startTime)
```

Comment: Impressive, now takes 0,12 seconds !! You are my today god. :)

Comment: I would have calculated the threshold once and used it in the conditional: ```threshold = 0.5 * size``` then ```{... if v > threshold}```.

Comment: Hmm, yeah definitely. Thanks I updated it along with some name errors.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a need for speed:

I was curious so I tried a *homespun* version of counter.  I actually thought it would Not be faster but I am getting better performance than `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections
def counter(s):
    '''counts the (hashable) things in s

    returns a collections.defaultdict -> {thing:count}
    '''
    a = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for c in s:
        a[c] += 1
    return a
```

This could be substituted into @DTing s solution - I wouldn't change any of that.

Guess it wasn't *homespun* at all, it is listed in the [`defaultdict` examples](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) in the docs.